# Navigation similar to UINavigationController in AngularJS webapp

Tags: cocoa-touch, angularjs

I want my webapp to behave just like other iPhone apps using a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

I wish to start with two views: the root view and a navigation bar.

When a new view should be shown, it will be put on top of the current one, merely hiding the previous view(s).

The navigation bar should show the title of the current view, along with a back button (unless root view).

Comment: And what this has to do with AngularJs?

Comment: @asgoth I'm using it to build my application, and I want to use it for this.

Comment: But do you mean you want to interact between your angularjs webapp and your native UINavigationController component? You didnt really say what your problem is.

Comment: I want it to behave like the navigation controller. Instead of replacing the "main view" I have, I want to add a new one on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at [ng-view](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angView).  It allows you to easily switch between views.  Also look at the [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) service.  It supports the browser's forward/back buttons.

If you want more control, or you don't want the brower's address bar to change when you switch views, you can manually hook things up with [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) and/or [ng-hide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHide) to show/hide sections of the DOM.  Use model/$scope properties to keep track of the current view and previous views.  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/sStUf/) showing how to get started.  E.g., the navigation bar might look something like this:

```
<button ng-hide="view == 'root'" ng-click="goBack()">< {{previousView}}</button>
```

And switching views:

```
<div ng-show="view == 'view1'">View 1
   <div><a ng-click="changeView('view1.1')">view 1.1</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, I'll fiddle around with this! Thank you.